# Can I remove some lines from some files when archiving them with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a task to archive some required files in my Gradle config:

```
task zip4BuildServer(type: Zip) {
    classifier = 'src'
    from projectDir
    include 'src/**/*'
    include 'lib/**/*'
    include 'gradle/**/*'
    include 'build.gradle'
    include 'settings.gradle'
    include 'data_source.xml'
    include 'gradlew'
    include 'gradlew.bat'
    archiveName "${baseName}-${getDate()}-${revision}.${extension}"
}
```

I would like to remove some lines from `build.gradle` inside archive (not in source place).

How to do that?

If I write this way

```
    from projectDir
    {
        eachFile { FileCopyDetails details ->
            if(details.file.text.contains("some word")) {
            }
        }
    }
```

it says

```
212: Ambiguous expression could be a parameterless closure expression, an isolated open code block, or it may continue a previous statement;
   solution: Add an explicit parameter list, e.g. {it -> ...}, or force it to be treated as an open block by giving it a label, e.g. L:{...}, and also either remove the previous newline, or add an explicit semicolon ';' @ line 212, column 5.
       {
       ^

1 error
```

How to fix? I don't understand the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It should work this way:

```
task zip4BuildServer(type: Zip) {
    classifier = 'src'
    from projectDir
    include 'src/**/*'
    include 'lib/**/*'
    include 'gradle/**/*'
    include 'build.gradle'
    include 'settings.gradle'
    include 'data_source.xml'
    include 'gradlew'
    include 'gradlew.bat'
    archiveName "${baseName}-${getDate()}-${revision}.${extension}"
    eachFile { FileCopyDetails details ->
       if(details.file.text.contains("some word")) {
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from projectDir
{
    eachFile { FileCopyDetails details ->
        if(details.file.text.contains("some word")) {
        }
    }
}
```

does not work, because this is two expressions, `from projectDir` followed by something Groovy is not sure what you want, an unused closure, a code block, ... just like the error describes. In Groovy a newline character can terminate an expression if it is complete. (No unclosed parentheses, no unclosed quotes, ...). So if you would write

```
from(projectDir) {
    eachFile { FileCopyDetails details ->
        if(details.file.text.contains("some word")) {
        }
    }
}
```

it should actually work, but I would simply do it like this:

```
from projectDir
eachFile { FileCopyDetails details ->
    if(details.file.text.contains("some word")) {
    }
}
```

or in my opinion even better like this:

```
from projectDir
filter { it.contains('some word') ? null : it }
```

But be aware that you should only filter text files. If you apply filters to binary files, you might destroy the binary files in the process. This does not only apply to the last solution, but also to the `eachFile` solution.

If you also have binary files in your copy spec, you might e. g. want to use `filesMatching` like

```
from projectDir
filesMatching(['build.gradle', '**/*.java']) {
    filter { it.contains('some word') ? null : it }
}
```